# how can i use arabic or french date format on my form widget in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

## forms.py

```
class QuittanceRegister(forms.Form):
    du=forms.DateField(required =True,widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs= {'type': 'date'}))
    au=forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
```

Edit : format code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')
```

and then in the **forms.py**

```
class QuittanceRegister(forms.Form):
    du=forms.DateField(required =True,widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs= {'type': 'date'}), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    au=forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

---

You can also use following line in settings.py

```
USE_L10N = True
```

but I had hard time with this in the past.